# Count the number of words read from a file and stored in a list by accessing the list

Tags: java

I am reading from the disk and storing the contents of a file using:

`BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file)))`

and then

`list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());`

The `list` is accessible from other methods in the class. How do I use it to get the count of words read from the file. 
I have tried list.count() but it gives a wrong value.

I tried a few lambda functions even those were giving me only the count of distinct words but not the total word count. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: You read lines, not words.

Comment: First you need to define what is a word? Is it just space separated text or is it more complex?

Comment: Do you need to handle large text files?

Answer (score 0):

You read lines, not words.

If you want the number of words in a file, use

```
int numLines;
try (var lines = Files.lines(Path.of(file))) {
    numLines = lines.filter(l -> !l.isBlank()).mapToInt(w -> w.split("\\h").length).sum()
}
```

Comment: I think, since the lines are already in a list (OP says it's accessible to other methods, so presumably it exists for other purposes than just counting the words), it is better to use the list rather than read the file again.

Comment: The part with `Files.newBufferedReader().lines()` is not the best way. Just use `Files.lines()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a list of lines, you will need a way of counting the words in a line:

```java
private static int countWordsInLine(String line) {
    line = line.trim();
    return line.isEmpty() ? 0 : line.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

From there, you just need to sum over the lines in the list:

```java
private int wordCount() {
    return lines.stream().mapToInt(ThisClass::countWordsInLine).sum();
}
```

Replace `ThisClass` with the name of the class that `countWordsInLine` is declared in.